# i can´t select text in big query studio with the mouse or the trackpad

Tags: select, text, google-bigquery, mouse

please help, i know someone will know hoy to fix this.
i cant select the text or part of the text in my big query studio.
im using chrome, if i use safari it works, i tried deleting chrome and installing it again, deleting the extensions, but noting works, what can it be??

[this is what im unable to to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As65I.png)

i tried deleting chrome and installing it again, deleting the extensions, but noting works, what can it be??

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the latest Chrome update and refreshed the BigQuery tab and I can highlight text again today.